# What is CIVector's CIAttributeTypeRectangle?

Tags: core-image

I am using Apple's Core Image Filter reference. It references:
"A CIVector class whose attribute type is CIAttributeTypeRectangle and whose display name is Rectangle."

I can't find anything anywhere that tells me anything about "attribute type is CIAttributeTypeRectangle" and what "display name is Rectangle." means.

[Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000136-SW160) (look under the CICrop Section)

Answer (score 0):

It should probably say `kCIAttributeTypeRectangle` rather than `CIAttributeTypeRectangle`. It refers to:

> `kCIAttributeTypeRectangle`
>
> A Core Image vector that specifies the *x* and
> *y* values of the rectangle origin, and the width (*w*) and height (*h*) of
> the rectangle. The vector takes the form *[x, y, w, h]*. (A 4-element
> vector type.)

See [kCIAttributeTypeRectangle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCIAttributeTypeRectangle).

I believe whenever it talks about a "Display name", it's referring to the display name for that particular parameter in Quartz Composer.